# What is the main difference between a free particle on a line and a free particle on a circle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

The energy spectrum for a free particle in a circle with radius $r$ is $$E_n=\frac{n^2\hbar^2}{2mr^2}.$$

The energy spectrum for a free particle on an infinite line is similar. If so, what is the main difference between either?

Comment: Discrete vs continuous spectra is probably the main difference.

Answer (score 2):

They both have the form $\hbar^2 k^2 / (2 m)$; this is a general consequence of the de Broglie relation that $p = h / \lambda$ (where $h$ is Planck's constant and $\lambda$ is the wavelength) combined with the wave number expression $k = 2\pi/\lambda$ and classical kinetic energy expression $\hbar = h / (2 \pi)$ and $\hat T = p^2/(2m)$. So for all free particles you'll see something of that form.

On the infinite line, $k$ is continuous. On the circle, the fact that the wavefunction has to "meet back up with itself again" after going around by $2\pi$ means that the waves become quantized; so in general if  $C = n\,\lambda$ where $n$ is an integer, $\lambda$ is still the wavelength, and $C = 2\pi r$ is the circumference of the ring: then $k = 2\pi/\lambda = n/r$ and you therefore get $\hbar^2 n^2 / (2 m r^2)$ simply by replacing $k$ with $n/r$.

Comment: This answer is correct, but going a little deeper, it comes down to the different topologies of the two spaces. In particular, note that the circle is compact, while the line is not. To really, *really* get to the heart of the matter, momentum is something called the Pontryagin dual of position,  a thing defined for any abelian, locally compact, topological group. The Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, while the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{S}^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, the momentum in the line case can be any real number, but in the circle case, it can only be an integer.